# Is Partial SSL Possible? ( multisite )

Tags: multisite, ssl

I have recently been invited to the letsencrypt SSL beta, and have now spotted a potential problem.

My main site tomjn.com is a multisite, and I have the opportunity to add certificates for tomjn.com and www.tomjn.com, but I also have other subdomains, subdomains i do not have SSL certificates for.

Is it possible to have tomjn.com served over SSL via WordPress, but only tomjn.com? Or must I force all the blogs/sites in my install to use SSL? If so, how is this best done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution in the end was to modify the `home` and `siteurl` options to include `https` in the url, rather than `http`, which set WordPress to use https by default for my main site, but not the others. As I acquire certificates for the other subdomains I can modify the options on those sites to enable SSL

Additional server configuration to set up SSL only on nginx was necessary but that's server configuration not WordPress

Answer (score 1):

Yes - entirely possible to use SSL on only 1 site in a WP network.  In the past, we have done this using .htaccess to force HTTPS for all URLs of a particular site, leaving all others HTTP.

This was done using carefully written Apache URL rewrites.

The SSL used was a wildcard cert although that will not impact how the server rewrites URLs.

Comment: Tom if needed I can try to access those .htaccess rules.  Lots of good examples on SE, too